# How can I get variables from URL using Python(2.7)?

Tags: python-2.7, http

The following works when I paste it on the browser:

```
localhost://api/get_url.py?x=xxx&y=yyy
```

how can i store the values of x and y in a variable passing from url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `requests` module has made it really simple.

Please read: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

```
import requests
response = requests.get('localhost://api/get_url.py', params={'x': x, 'y': y})
```

Comment: thanks for your replay ... its working fine @blhsing